# Yii. Как передать данные нескольких моделей в CGridView?

Tags: php, yii

Как передать данные для поиска и сортировки из нескольких AR моделей в виджет CGridView? Не люблю опускаться до кода, но... в основном код в принципе сгенерен модулем gii:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'ch-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'name' => 'title',
        'header' => 'Заголовок',
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'category.title',
        'header' => 'Категория',
        'filter' => CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'title'),
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'chValue.title',
        'header' => 'Величина'     
    ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
),
```

));

проблема в том, что виджет плевать хотел на поиск и сортировку в полях, выбранных с помощью отношений (category.title).
я совсем не понимаю, как это работает. объясните мне, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю, и как мне добавить поиск по разным моделям в одном grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для сортировки в модели в функции search надо добавить.

```
$criteria->with = array('category');
$criteria->together = true;
return new CActiveDataProvider('Model', array(
          'criteria'=>$criteria,
          'sort'=>array(
            'attributes'=>array(
              'categorytitle'=>array(
                'asc'=>'category.title',
                'desc'=>'category.title DESC',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
```

Для поиска надо будет добавить виртуальное поле.

```
private $_categorytitle = NULL;
public function getCategorytitle()
{
  if ($this->_categorytitle == NULL)
    $this->_categorytitle = $this->category->title;
  return $this->_categorytitle;
}
public function setCategorytitle($value)
{
  $this->_categorytitle = $value;
}
```

В функции rules в массив надо добавить

```
array('categorytitle', 'safe')
```

Во вьюхе в виджете заменить category.title на categorytitle.

Comment: Извини, ошибка вышла. Вместо:
if ($this->_categorytitle == NULL)
    $this->_categorytitle = $this->category->title;
  return $this->_categorytitle;
Надо:
if (($this->_categorytitle == NULL) && ($this->category))
    $this->_categorytitle = $this->category->title;
  return $this->_categorytitle;

Comment: В первом варианте не проверялось наличие найденной категории (т.е. эта модель соответствует найденной строке из БД или эта модель сгенерирована виджетом, а значит заполнена данными из поискового запроса). Во втором варианте эти случаи учитываются.

Comment: а не подскажешь ещё, как мне разрешить конфликт имен у category.title и title самой модели?
ругается на вот это

>> ambiguous column name: title

и ещё вопрос, что-нибудь можно поделать, если таких псевдополей должно быть много? спасибо за помощь

Comment: Где именно ругается?
Если в функции search, то надо в строке где сравнивается название категории заменить title на category.title. Должно получиться:
$criteria->compare('category.title', $this->categorytitle, true);

Comment: >> где сравнивается название категории заменить title на category.title

у меня вообще нет подобной строки 

>> $criteria->compare('category.title', $this->categorytitle, true);

я ещё не полностью разобрался, как работает dbcriteria и поэтому тупо сделал по вашему примеру.

>> $criteria->with = array('category');
$criteria->together = true;

всё же должна быть строка с compare?

Comment: вот весь код, что греха таить http://pastebin.com/HcHUPx22

где в коде возникает ошибка не пойму, yii выкидывает её алертом, я лично ничего не понял. http://pastebin.com/6rfm6XJQ

Comment: Понятно теперь.

Вот мой код http://pastebin.com/z4srjMUA

Ошибка была в строке:

    $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);

Исправил на:

    $criteria->compare('t.title',$this->title,true);

СУБД не знала с полем из какой таблицы сравнивать.

Comment: спасибо огромное! хотел бы я быть таким спецом!!! расти мне ещё и расти... даже не представляю, как можно настолько хорошо разбираться. ни на одном форуме ещё ни одного толкового решения не нашел, а прошарил сегодня не мало их.